# What is the convention follow to put a private library when installing from a .deb package?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I have a library that I must install, for not being widely available and to ease packaging in my own .deb package. The file is a `.so` file and I will set the RUNPATH for it to find some other dependency.

Where should I put my private installed library? It is an architecture independent file that is read-only, but I could not find anywhere a conclusion on where to store that file exactly. Given that PREFIX=/usr,
where should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should go in a private directory in `lib/`. I deduced this from looking at http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html and lintian was warning me to not put any arch-specific file in `/usr/share`.

So the correct place to place private files is `/usr/lib/mypackagename`.

Comment: Yes, /usr/lib/libfoo.so and /usr/lib/bar/libfoo.so are both good candidate names. The first one will allow executable to be linked to the library without any special aid in order to link/start.